# Does Exit Function return false?

Tags: vb.net

In VB.NET on a boolean function if you run an Exit Function line will it return false?

Comment: This is why I don;t like VB :) In C# the compiler forces you to return explicity.

Comment: Actually compiler tells you as a warning (and/or visually) if you don't return anything explicitly, I'm not quite sure if it's possible to make it mandatory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That is correct, with the caveat that in VB the function name can also be a variable that is returned.  If you've previously set that to true, it will return true.

---

More completely, in VB.Net, if I have a boolean function `Foo()` defined like so:

```
Public Function Foo() As Boolean
   '...
```

...the body of that function has an implied variable also named `Foo` that matches the return type of the function — `Boolean` in this case, but `Object` if the return type is omitted (you should be using `Option Strict`, which requires a return type). This implied variable is initialized to use the default value for that type.

If you fail to `Return` a value from the function, whether via `Exit Function` or simply by reaching the end, this implied variable is returned instead. Therefore, a `Boolean` function will return `False` if you `Exit Function` early without making other changes, because that is the default value in the implied variable used with the function. But you could also set that variable to `True` first if you wanted, and then `Exit Function` would cause it to return `True` instead.

These days people don't often use the implied variable, but there are situations where it can save you a few lines of code without costing anything in clarity.

Comment: Possibly this is a matter of clarity, but this works in VB because that function output variable is init'd to false and without an explicit return it's that variable which is returned

Comment: To be clear, if I have a function returning type long, `Exit Function` returns the default value (0). Furthermore, if, in my `Function Foo() as Long`, I `Return Foo`, I am, in fact, returning `0`. Correct? I could technically replace `Exit Function` with `Return Foo`?

Answer (score 3):

Regardless if it does or not (the compiler gives a null-reference warning only), you should still explicitly return false, if only for readability.

Comment: The actual answer to the question is still useful if you want to _clean up_ such `Exit Function` usage though.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have not set that function to True before you exit

Answer (score 2):

I always do "Return True" or "Return False" to exit a method instead of the exit statement.